# formula for alpha value when blending two transparent colors

Tags: colors, transparency, alpha, blending

lets assume an alpha of 1 means fully opaque and 0 means fully transparent.
lets say i have two black images which have 50% transparency (alpha = 0.5).

if they are laid on top of each other, the resulting transparency is 0.75, right?

if they would have an alpha of 0.25 , the result would be around 0.5, right?

if they would have an alpha of 0.9 , the result would be around 0.97, right?

how can you get to these numbers?

in other words i am looking for a function that gets the resulting alpha value from two other alpha value.

```
float alpha = f(float alphaBelow, float alphaAbove)
{
     //TODO implement
}
```

Comment: Conventionally, the color is opaque when alpha = 1, and fully transparent when alpha = 0. So the resulting alpha of laying a 50% on top of 50% should be 25%, not 75%.

Comment: @KennyTM, ok, i will edit my post to work with floats from 0 to 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer is mathematically the same as [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658804/formula-for-alpha-value-when-blending-two-transparent-colors/3658820#3658820), but this is the actual formula as you'll find it in reference material.

```
float blend(float alphaBelow, float alphaAbove) 
{ 
    return alphaBelow + (1.0 - alphaBelow) * alphaAbove; 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
float blend(float alphaBelow, float alphaAbove)
{
    return alphaBelow + alphaAbove - alphaBelow * alphaAbove;
}
```

This function assumes both parameters are 0..1, where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque.

Comment: thanks, it is almost like my wished result. it's just that when i compare the result with two images on top of each other in photoshop, the photoshop version seems to have a little higher alpha values.

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop does the following calculation:

```
float blend(float alphaBelow, float alphaAbove)
{
    return min(1,alphaBelow+(1-alphaBelow)*alphaAbove);
}
```

Comment: The `min` is redundant if both inputs are in the 0..1 range.